# Can Azure Remote Monitoring IoT Suite preconfigured solution running on local machine fully?

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

We did explore the Microsoft IoT Suite preconfigured solution previously created via their portal and with this we realise it's pure 100% in Azure. Then we are exploring via GitHub and we found partially deployment can be done via dev machine and Azure.

Can Azure Remote Monitoring IoT Suite preconfigured solution running on local machine fully (no Azure till it's fully working)?

The reason we asked this due to IoT Azure is a bit pricy for development/demo around $200/month to operate even after we are configured with basic service as some Azure component can't downgrade to the free one once setup as higher service.

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-remote-monitoring/blob/master/Docs/local-deployment.md) you refer to describes how to run the Remote Monitoring deployment scripts locally instead of using the azureiotsuite.com site. Running the scripts locally still creates a number of services in your Azure subscription.

A couple of other things to note:

- For test and development you can use an [Azure free trial account](https://azure.microsoft.com/free/).
- You can minimize the costs of your Remote Monitoring deployment during test and development using [this guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-remote-monitoring/blob/master/Docs/configure-preconfigured-demo.md).

Comment: I think that what we did explaining on the guide as we did trial and error. BUT will try to follow that guide that to see if the cost is minimised or not.